# How can you delete the books from 'Cloud' in Kindle PaperWhite?

Tags: kindle

I'm using this Google Chrome [Push to Kindle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/push-to-kindle/pnaiinchjaonopoejhknmgjingcnaloc?hl=en) extension for reading articles on the kindle. In short it converts an article and sends it to your device.

It's very convenient, but I've collected a lot of article in my Kindle 'Cloud' and I can't find a way to delete them.

Tried in Amazon - Manage your device and content, but there I can see only the bought books.

Any ideas how to delete the cloud books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha, I figured it out. You need to log in to your amazon account from a PC or laptop.

1. Go to **MANAGE YOUR CONTENT AND DEVICES** on amazon.com
2. Select **MANAGE YOUR CONTENT**.
3. For the dropdown labeled **SHOW**, change it from BOOKS to **DOCS**.

From there, you will see all your personal content and be able to delete content.